# Blazor application can't find nested model

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, blazor

I have this Blazor application where I have the following model class:

```
    public class Purchase
{
    public Payment payment { get; set; }
}

public class Payment
{
    public string operation { get; set; }
    public string intent { get; set; }
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public Price[] prices { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string userAgent { get; set; }
    public string language { get; set; }
    public Urls urls { get; set; }
    public Payeeinfo payeeInfo { get; set; }
    public Cardholder cardholder { get; set; }
    public Riskindicator riskIndicator { get; set; }
}

public class Urls
{
    public string completeUrl { get; set; }
    public string cancelUrl { get; set; }
    public string callbackUrl { get; set; }
    public string logoUrl { get; set; }
    public string termsOfServiceUrl { get; set; }
}

public class Payeeinfo
{
    public string payeeId { get; set; }
    public string payeeReference { get; set; }
    public string payeeName { get; set; }
    public string productCategory { get; set; }
    public string orderReference { get; set; }
    public string subsite { get; set; }
}

public class Cardholder
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string msisdn { get; set; }
    public string homePhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string workPhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public Shippingaddress shippingAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Shippingaddress
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string msisdn { get; set; }
    public string streetAddress { get; set; }
    public string coAddress { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string zipCode { get; set; }
    public string countryCode { get; set; }
}

public class Riskindicator
{
    public string deliveryEmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string deliveryTimeFrameIndicator { get; set; }
    public string preOrderDate { get; set; }
    public string preOrderPurchaseIndicator { get; set; }
    public string shipIndicator { get; set; }
    public bool giftCardPurchase { get; set; }
    public string reOrderPurchaseIndicator { get; set; }
    public Pickupaddress pickUpAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Pickupaddress
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string streetAddress { get; set; }
    public string coAddress { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string zipCode { get; set; }
    public string countryCode { get; set; }
}

public class Price
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int amount { get; set; }
    public int vatAmount { get; set; }
}
```

I try to implement this like this in the razor component:

```
@page "/testpay"
@using Kanal10.UI.Models.Payex

<!-- Content -->
<div class="donate">
    <div class="donate-pay wrapper">
        <EditForm Model="purchase" OnValidSubmit="SavePurchase">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Firstname</label>
                        <InputText id="firstName" @bind-value="purchase.payment.cardholder.firstName" class="form-control"></InputText>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </EditForm>


    </div>
</div>
@code {
    private Purchase purchase = new Purchase();

    private void SavePurchase()
    {

    }
}
```

But when I render the page I get error message and I can't quite understand why.

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Kanal10.UI.Pages.PayTest.b__0_1(RenderTreeBuilder __builder2)

If someone has an answer I would be most grateful.

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do something like this:

```
<InputText id="firstName" @bind-value="purchase.payment.cardholder.firstName" class="form-control"></InputText>
```

You must do something like this:

```
@code
{
    private Purchase purchase = new Purchase { payment=new Payment() 
                                    {cardholder=new Cardholder(){}}};
}
```

This should work, provided I did not miss something in the chain. But the principal is clear: You must instantiate an object embedded in an instantiation of parent object which itself is embedded in an instantiation of grand parent object, and so on and so forth. That is not something related to Blazor. This is C#. You must instantiate an object before you can use it, no ?

Note: The Name of the field, as for instance, `payment` in

```
public Payment payment { get; set; }
```

not only can be named `Payment`, but by convention we define it so (especially starting with capital letter). So make it `public Payment Payment{ get; set; }`

Comment: Super, that explains it. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Try the nested object  validator https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#nested-models-collection-types-and-complex-types

Also, try initializing your nested models so they are not null

Comment: I initialize like this:
  protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        purchase = new Purchase();
        payment = new Payment();
        cardHolder = new Cardholder();

    }
Still same error

Comment: Try adding these to your model fields as default values